# Keras Soft Actor-Critic for discrete actions - policy loss staying at zero

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

Using Keras, I am trying to implement a soft actor-critic model for discrete action spaces. However, the policy loss remains unchanged (fluctuating around zero), and as a result, the agent architecture cannot learn successfully.

I am unclear where the issue is as I have used a PyTorch implementation as a reference which does work successfully. Here is the link to the git repo that my code is based on  [SAC discrete pytorch](https://github.com/BY571/SAC_discrete). I've run both models for 8,000 episodes and only the PyTorch version is able to successfully converge. Can anyone help me diagnose the issue in the code?

Below is my code using Keras as well as output for both my and the PyTorch version. I should add both implementations were tested on the Lunar Lander environment with discrete actions.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
import numpy as np
import random
import gym
from collections import deque
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from copy import deepcopy
import gym
tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float64')
tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(
    True
)

MAX_EPISODES =8000 

def make_env(env_name, seed=None):
    # remove time limit wrapper from environment
    env = gym.make(env_name).unwrapped
    if seed is not None:
        env.seed(seed)
    return env

# set a seed
seed = 13
random.seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)
tf.random.set_seed(seed)

#setup env and agent and target networks
env_name = 'LunarLander-v2'
env = make_env(env_name, seed)
state_dim = env.observation_space.shape
n_actions = env.action_space.n
state = env.reset()

def collect_random(env, dataset, num_samples=200):
    state = env.reset()
    for _ in range(num_samples):
        action = env.action_space.sample()
        next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
        transition = (state, action, reward, next_state, done)
        dataset.add_transition(transition)
        state = next_state
        if done:
            state = env.reset()


class Actor2Network(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, state_size, action_size) -> None:
        super(Actor2Network, self).__init__()
        self.linear1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')
        self.linear2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')
        self.linear3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(action_size)    
        self.softmax = tf.keras.layers.Softmax(axis=1)   

    def call(self, state):        
        out1 = self.linear1(state)
        out2 = self.linear2(out1)
        mean = self.linear3(out2)
        action_probs = self.softmax(mean)
        return action_probs


def hidden_init(hidden_layers):
    fan_in = hidden_layers
    lim = 1. / np.sqrt(fan_in)
    return (-lim, lim)

class CriticNetwork(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, state_dim, action_size) -> None:
        super(CriticNetwork,self).__init__()
        lims = hidden_init(256)
        initializer = tf.keras.initializers.RandomUniform(minval=lims[0], maxval=lims[1])
        self.linear1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu',kernel_initializer=initializer)
        self.linear2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu',kernel_initializer=initializer)
        initializer = tf.keras.initializers.RandomUniform(minval=-3e-3, maxval=3e-3)
        self.output_layer =  tf.keras.layers.Dense(action_size,kernel_initializer=initializer)
    
    def call(self, state):
        out1 = self.linear1(state)
        out2 = self.linear2(out1)
        x = self.output_layer(out2)
        return x

class ReplayBuffer:
    def __init__(self, environment, capacity=1000000):
        transition_type_str = self.get_transition_type_str(environment)
        self.buffer = np.zeros(capacity, dtype=transition_type_str)
        self.weights = np.zeros(capacity)
        self.head_idx = 0
        self.count = 0
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.max_weight = 10**-2
        self.delta = 10**-4
        self.indices = None

    def get_transition_type_str(self, environment):
        state_dim = environment.observation_space.shape[0]
        state_dim_str = '' if state_dim == () else str(state_dim)
        state_type_str = environment.observation_space.sample().dtype.name
        action_dim = environment.action_space.shape
        action_dim_str = '' if action_dim == () else str(action_dim)
        action_type_str = environment.action_space.sample().__class__.__name__
        # type str for transition = 'state type, action type, reward type, state type'
        transition_type_str = '{0}{1}, {2}{3}, float32, {0}{1}, bool'.format(state_dim_str, state_type_str,
                                                                             action_dim_str, action_type_str)
        return transition_type_str
    def add_transition(self, transition):
        self.buffer[self.head_idx] = transition
        self.weights[self.head_idx] = self.max_weight
        self.head_idx = (self.head_idx + 1) % self.capacity
        self.count = min(self.count + 1, self.capacity)

    def sample_minibatch(self, size=100):
        self.indices = np.random.choice(range(self.count), size, replace=False)
        return self.buffer[self.indices]

    def get_size(self):
        return self.count

class SACAgent:
    ALPHA_INITIAL = 0.0 # 1. 
    REPLAY_BUFFER_BATCH_SIZE = 256
    LEARNING_RATE = 5e-4 #0.001 

    def __init__(self,environment):
        self.environment = environment
        self.state_dim = self.environment.observation_space.shape[0]
        self.action_dim = self.environment.action_space.n  
        self.tau = 1e-2
        self.gamma = 0.99    
        self.target_entropy = -tf.constant(self.action_dim, dtype=tf.float32)      
        self.log_alpha = tf.Variable(self.ALPHA_INITIAL,trainable=True, dtype=tf.float64)
        self.alpha = tf.stop_gradient(tf.math.exp(self.log_alpha))
        self.alpha_optimiser = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=self.LEARNING_RATE)
        #Actor Network
        self.agent_local = Actor2Network(self.state_dim, self.action_dim)
        self.actor_optimiser = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=self.LEARNING_RATE)          
       #New Critic Network
        self.critic_local = CriticNetwork(self.state_dim, self.action_dim) #critic1
        self.critic_local2 = CriticNetwork(self.state_dim, self.action_dim) #critic2        
        self.critic_target = CriticNetwork(self.state_dim,self.action_dim)
        self.critic_target2 = CriticNetwork(self.state_dim,self.action_dim)
        self.critic_optimiser = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=self.LEARNING_RATE)
        self.critic_optimiser2 = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=self.LEARNING_RATE)
        self.replay_buffer = ReplayBuffer(self.environment)
        collect_random(self.environment, self.replay_buffer, 10000)
        self.MSEloss =  tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()


    def get_action_info(self, states_tensor, batch = False):
        if batch:
            batch_size = states_tensor.shape[0]
            action_probabilities = self.agent_local(states_tensor)
        else:
            batch_size=0
            action_probabilities = self.agent_local(states_tensor[np.newaxis])
        action_probabilities = tf.squeeze(action_probabilities)
        if batch:
            discrete_action = [np.random.choice(range(self.action_dim), p=action_probabilities[i,:]) 
                                for i in range(batch_size)]
        else:
            discrete_action = np.random.choice(range(self.action_dim), p=action_probabilities)
        z = action_probabilities == 0.0
        z = tf.cast(z, tf.float64) * 1e-8
        log_action_probabilities = tf.math.log(tf.cast(action_probabilities, tf.float64) + z)
        return discrete_action, action_probabilities, log_action_probabilities

    def learn(self, states_tensor,actions_tensor,rewards_tensor,next_states_tensor,done_tensor, current_alpha):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape1:
            _, pi_a, log_pi_a = self.get_action_info(states_tensor, batch=True)       
            q_values_local = tf.squeeze(self.critic_local(states_tensor))
            q_values_local2 = tf.squeeze(self.critic_local2(states_tensor))
            min_q = tf.minimum(q_values_local, q_values_local2)
            soft_q = tf.reduce_sum(pi_a * tf.squeeze(current_alpha * log_pi_a - min_q),axis=1)
            actor_loss = tf.reduce_mean(soft_q)
            log_action_pi = tf.reduce_sum(log_pi_a * pi_a, axis = 1)
            actor_loss, log_action_pi = tf.cast(actor_loss, tf.float32), tf.cast(log_action_pi, tf.float32)

        grads = tape1.gradient(actor_loss, self.agent_local.trainable_variables)
        self.actor_optimiser.apply_gradients(zip(grads,self.agent_local.trainable_variables))  

        with tf.GradientTape() as tapeA:
            alpha_loss = tf.reduce_mean( -tf.cast(tf.math.exp(self.log_alpha), tf.float32)*(log_action_pi + self.target_entropy))
        variables = [self.log_alpha]
        grads = tapeA.gradient(alpha_loss, variables)
        self.alpha_optimiser.apply_gradients(zip(grads,variables))
        self.alpha = tf.stop_gradient(tf.math.exp(self.log_alpha))


        with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape2:
            _, pi_a, log_pi_a = self.get_action_info(states_tensor, batch=True)
            critic_local_output = tf.cast(self.critic_local(states_tensor), tf.float32)
            critic_local2_output = tf.cast(self.critic_local2(states_tensor), tf.float32)
            next_q_values_target = tf.squeeze(self.critic_target(next_states_tensor))
            next_q_values_target2 = tf.squeeze(self.critic_target2(next_states_tensor))
            min_q_target = tf.minimum(next_q_values_target, next_q_values_target2)
            soft_q_target = tf.reduce_sum((pi_a * (min_q_target - self.alpha * log_pi_a)),1)
            y = tf.stop_gradient (rewards_tensor + (1.0 - tf.cast(done_tensor, tf.float32)) * self.gamma*tf.cast(soft_q_target, tf.float32))     
            critic_policy = tf.gather(critic_local_output, tf.squeeze(actions_tensor), batch_dims=1)
            critic1_loss =  0.5 * self.MSEloss(critic_policy, y)
            critic_policy2 = tf.gather(critic_local2_output, tf.squeeze(actions_tensor), batch_dims=1)
            critic2_loss =  0.5 * self.MSEloss(critic_policy2, y)
   
        grads1 = tape2.gradient(critic1_loss, self.critic_local.trainable_variables)
        grads1, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(grads1, 1.0)
        self.critic_optimiser.apply_gradients(zip(grads1, self.critic_local.trainable_variables))
        grads2 = tape2.gradient(critic2_loss, self.critic_local2.trainable_variables)
        grads2, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(grads2, 1.0)
        self.critic_optimiser2.apply_gradients(zip(grads2, self.critic_local2.trainable_variables))

        return critic1_loss, critic2_loss, actor_loss, log_action_pi, alpha_loss

    def train_on_transition(self, state, discrete_action, next_state, reward, done):
        transition = (state, discrete_action, reward, next_state, done)
        return self.train_all_networks(transition)


    def train_all_networks(self, transition):
        self.replay_buffer.add_transition(transition) 
        current_alpha = deepcopy(self.alpha)
        minibatch = self.replay_buffer.sample_minibatch(self.REPLAY_BUFFER_BATCH_SIZE)
        minibatch_separated = list(map(list, zip(*minibatch)))
        states_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array(minibatch_separated[0]), tf.float32)#[np.newaxis]
        actions_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array(minibatch_separated[1]))[np.newaxis]
        rewards_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array(minibatch_separated[2]),tf.float32)#.float()
        next_states_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array(minibatch_separated[3]),tf.float32)#[np.newaxis]
        done_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array(minibatch_separated[4]))
        
        critic1_loss, critic2_loss, actor_loss, log_actions, alpha_loss = self.learn(states_tensor,actions_tensor,rewards_tensor,next_states_tensor,done_tensor, current_alpha)
        self.update_weights()
        return critic1_loss, critic2_loss, actor_loss, alpha_loss


    def update_weights(self):
        for theta_target, theta in zip(self.critic_target.trainable_variables, self.critic_local.trainable_variables):
            theta_target = self.tau * theta + (1 - self.tau) * theta_target

        for theta_target, theta in zip(self.critic_target2.trainable_variables, self.critic_local2.trainable_variables):
            theta_target = self.tau * theta + (1 - self.tau) * theta_target
    

TRAINING_EVALUATION_RATIO = 4
RUNS = 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    env = make_env(env_name, seed)
    agent_results = []

    steps = 0
    total_steps = 0
    agent = SACAgent( env)
    run_results = []
    for i in range(MAX_EPISODES+1):
        state = env.reset()
        episode_steps = 0
        rewards = 0
        while True:
            action, _, _ = agent.get_action_info(state)
            steps += 1
            next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
            critic1_loss, critic2_loss, actor_loss, alpha_loss = agent.train_on_transition(state, action, next_state, reward, done)
            state = next_state
            rewards += reward
            episode_steps += 1
            if done:
                break
        run_results.append(rewards)            
        total_steps += episode_steps
        print("Episode: {} | Reward: {} | Polciy Loss: {} | Steps: {}".format(i, rewards, actor_loss.numpy(), steps,))
        print("            | Alpha Value: {} |AlphaLoss: {} | Critic Loss: {} | Critic 2 Loss: {}".format(agent.alpha, alpha_loss.numpy(), critic1_loss.numpy(), critic2_loss.numpy(),))
    agent_results.append(run_results))
```

Provided below is the output of 20 episodes using Keras. Note that the policy loss does not increase or decrease drastically.

```
Episode: 0 | Reward: -382.6865058889616 | Polciy Loss: -0.570154070854187 | Steps: 89
            | Alpha Value: 0.9568648464938605 |AlphaLoss: 5.069327354431152 | Critic Loss: 83.68002319335938 | Critic 2 Loss: 83.08641815185547
Episode: 1 | Reward: -177.14849241050308 | Polciy Loss: -1.064318299293518 | Steps: 216
            | Alpha Value: 0.900349543665257 |AlphaLoss: 4.656105041503906 | Critic Loss: 61.42171096801758 | Critic 2 Loss: 61.95112609863281
Episode: 2 | Reward: -97.35798536781431 | Polciy Loss: -0.32244303822517395 | Steps: 305
            | Alpha Value: 0.8641899902008849 |AlphaLoss: 4.409027099609375 | Critic Loss: 40.204341888427734 | Critic 2 Loss: 40.56953430175781
Episode: 3 | Reward: -355.35859072203976 | Polciy Loss: -0.62746661901474 | Steps: 500
            | Alpha Value: 0.7918289680487987 |AlphaLoss: 4.027188301086426 | Critic Loss: 7.248492240905762 | Critic 2 Loss: 7.382608413696289
Episode: 4 | Reward: -399.7873643463884 | Polciy Loss: -0.12188385426998138 | Steps: 584
            | Alpha Value: 0.7633374790595959 |AlphaLoss: 3.7960591316223145 | Critic Loss: 45.05104064941406 | Critic 2 Loss: 44.82737731933594
Episode: 5 | Reward: -523.9425270248387 | Polciy Loss: -0.14518888294696808 | Steps: 721
            | Alpha Value: 0.7203133414602841 |AlphaLoss: 3.5572612285614014 | Critic Loss: 33.53896713256836 | Critic 2 Loss: 32.79704666137695
Episode: 6 | Reward: -74.79084611184531 | Polciy Loss: -0.659368634223938 | Steps: 868
            | Alpha Value: 0.6787260521922199 |AlphaLoss: 3.2354238033294678 | Critic Loss: 26.380695343017578 | Critic 2 Loss: 26.40806007385254
Episode: 7 | Reward: -150.2389551063632 | Polciy Loss: 0.42059123516082764 | Steps: 1025
            | Alpha Value: 0.6381739435594841 |AlphaLoss: 2.9750688076019287 | Critic Loss: 48.45856475830078 | Critic 2 Loss: 48.60898208618164
Episode: 8 | Reward: -256.66149131733926 | Polciy Loss: 0.3700742721557617 | Steps: 1188
            | Alpha Value: 0.5997676934509131 |AlphaLoss: 2.8072500228881836 | Critic Loss: 39.25719451904297 | Critic 2 Loss: 38.88347625732422
Episode: 9 | Reward: -202.68371538861766 | Polciy Loss: -0.33086907863616943 | Steps: 1552
            | Alpha Value: 0.5248583809357847 |AlphaLoss: 2.3362293243408203 | Critic Loss: 31.537277221679688 | Critic 2 Loss: 31.601444244384766
Episode: 10 | Reward: -111.06026429666674 | Polciy Loss: 0.1891651153564453 | Steps: 1837
            | Alpha Value: 0.47445880203360224 |AlphaLoss: 2.0930418968200684 | Critic Loss: 15.25515365600586 | Critic 2 Loss: 16.363637924194336
Episode: 11 | Reward: -334.0604630704215 | Polciy Loss: -0.05041874200105667 | Steps: 2256
            | Alpha Value: 0.41086207477773873 |AlphaLoss: 1.801985740661621 | Critic Loss: 49.47577667236328 | Critic 2 Loss: 49.37847137451172
Episode: 12 | Reward: -233.64710211338547 | Polciy Loss: -0.5285745859146118 | Steps: 2609
            | Alpha Value: 0.3650491985236877 |AlphaLoss: 1.560840368270874 | Critic Loss: 28.404239654541016 | Critic 2 Loss: 30.143714904785156
Episode: 13 | Reward: -246.67946137790386 | Polciy Loss: -0.25510096549987793 | Steps: 3005
            | Alpha Value: 0.32049881271779956 |AlphaLoss: 1.376400351524353 | Critic Loss: 24.744796752929688 | Critic 2 Loss: 24.191997528076172
Episode: 14 | Reward: -269.3330537494175 | Polciy Loss: -0.4212702512741089 | Steps: 3466
            | Alpha Value: 0.2762093811786384 |AlphaLoss: 1.1777863502502441 | Critic Loss: 34.79751205444336 | Critic 2 Loss: 34.62565994262695
Episode: 15 | Reward: -343.02294211066635 | Polciy Loss: -0.11738082766532898 | Steps: 3630
            | Alpha Value: 0.2621456515949704 |AlphaLoss: 1.1034882068634033 | Critic Loss: 23.084312438964844 | Critic 2 Loss: 22.173425674438477
Episode: 16 | Reward: -67.81571150908097 | Polciy Loss: -0.2141314446926117 | Steps: 3762
            | Alpha Value: 0.2513739748522983 |AlphaLoss: 1.0663121938705444 | Critic Loss: 23.843748092651367 | Critic 2 Loss: 24.26930046081543
Episode: 17 | Reward: -210.62139743419107 | Polciy Loss: -0.3545645773410797 | Steps: 3945
            | Alpha Value: 0.23719681517769847 |AlphaLoss: 0.9977421760559082 | Critic Loss: 93.76428985595703 | Critic 2 Loss: 94.36497497558594
Episode: 18 | Reward: -341.536999273625 | Polciy Loss: 0.14328444004058838 | Steps: 4378
            | Alpha Value: 0.20697361416347643 |AlphaLoss: 0.8705980777740479 | Critic Loss: 31.48116683959961 | Critic 2 Loss: 33.28431701660156
Episode: 19 | Reward: -212.42556268710877 | Polciy Loss: 0.5487046241760254 | Steps: 4618
            | Alpha Value: 0.19201773109063927 |AlphaLoss: 0.8208724856376648 | Critic Loss: 54.1052131652832 | Critic 2 Loss: 55.05682373046875
Episode: 20 | Reward: -73.49154391541926 | Polciy Loss: -0.18671931326389313 | Steps: 4756
            | Alpha Value: 0.18388786390662956 |AlphaLoss: 0.7654350996017456 | Critic Loss: 7.57553243637085 | Critic 2 Loss: 7.27564573
```

Provided below is the output of 20 episodes for the PyTorch version where the loss does fluctuate more.

```
Episode: 1 | Reward: -451.1679387131138 | Polciy Loss: -0.594589352607727 | Steps: 93
           | Alpha Value: tensor([0.9554]) | AlphaLoss: 4.907814979553223 | Critic Loss: 27.225311279296875 | Critic 2 Loss: 27.123432159423828
Episode: 2 | Reward: -222.4640629208855 | Polciy Loss: 0.3554394245147705 | Steps: 257
           | Alpha Value: tensor([0.8831]) | AlphaLoss: 4.647272109985352 | Critic Loss: 84.06465148925781 | Critic 2 Loss: 84.49320983886719
Episode: 3 | Reward: -173.82969052209586 | Polciy Loss: 0.5670033693313599 | Steps: 377
           | Alpha Value: tensor([0.8353]) | AlphaLoss: 4.26384162902832 | Critic Loss: 33.19162368774414 | Critic 2 Loss: 33.71275329589844
Episode: 4 | Reward: -192.50890459557354 | Polciy Loss: 1.0517194271087646 | Steps: 473
           | Alpha Value: tensor([0.8004]) | AlphaLoss: 4.010799884796143 | Critic Loss: 9.830133438110352 | Critic 2 Loss: 9.544718742370605
Episode: 5 | Reward: -175.69247167958747 | Polciy Loss: 2.5196194648742676 | Steps: 581
           | Alpha Value: tensor([0.7634]) | AlphaLoss: 3.8990180492401123 | Critic Loss: 32.75480270385742 | Critic 2 Loss: 32.90913391113281
Episode: 6 | Reward: -342.0030094486913 | Polciy Loss: 1.1028378009796143 | Steps: 693
           | Alpha Value: tensor([0.7281]) | AlphaLoss: 3.575157403945923 | Critic Loss: 6.4436235427856445 | Critic 2 Loss: 6.27545166015625
Episode: 7 | Reward: -266.28850817287804 | Polciy Loss: 3.536207437515259 | Steps: 1094
           | Alpha Value: tensor([0.6207]) | AlphaLoss: 2.849700927734375 | Critic Loss: 27.318885803222656 | Critic 2 Loss: 27.378366470336914
Episode: 8 | Reward: -267.03636253158203 | Polciy Loss: 4.48097562789917 | Steps: 1419
           | Alpha Value: tensor([0.5503]) | AlphaLoss: 2.4469680786132812 | Critic Loss: 8.608480453491211 | Critic 2 Loss: 8.671847343444824
Episode: 9 | Reward: -124.18404325965193 | Polciy Loss: 3.9400672912597656 | Steps: 1627
           | Alpha Value: tensor([0.5108]) | AlphaLoss: 2.3419878482818604 | Critic Loss: 16.08388328552246 | Critic 2 Loss: 16.209369659423828
Episode: 10 | Reward: -391.2392033768391 | Polciy Loss: 5.36818790435791 | Steps: 2627
           | Alpha Value: tensor([0.3630]) | AlphaLoss: 1.5480107069015503 | Critic Loss: 5.7878098487854 | Critic 2 Loss: 5.872251987457275
Episode: 11 | Reward: -114.05987597477926 | Polciy Loss: 4.345363140106201 | Steps: 3627
           | Alpha Value: tensor([0.2623]) | AlphaLoss: 1.107916235923767 | Critic Loss: 15.655235290527344 | Critic 2 Loss: 15.289471626281738
Episode: 12 | Reward: -16.122039538470265 | Polciy Loss: 3.3466103076934814 | Steps: 4627
           | Alpha Value: tensor([0.1909]) | AlphaLoss: 0.8068017363548279 | Critic Loss: 5.0585832595825195 | Critic 2 Loss: 5.201590538024902
Episode: 13 | Reward: -21.943749746230008 | Polciy Loss: -6.298027038574219 | Steps: 5627
           | Alpha Value: tensor([0.1397]) | AlphaLoss: 0.5904785990715027 | Critic Loss: 2.5069453716278076 | Critic 2 Loss: 2.3377370834350586
Episode: 14 | Reward: -26.242735364215072 | Polciy Loss: -5.422311782836914 | Steps: 6627
           | Alpha Value: tensor([0.1024]) | AlphaLoss: 0.43295818567276 | Critic Loss: 2.2447168827056885 | Critic 2 Loss: 2.2818055152893066
Episode: 15 | Reward: 134.93580700244672 | Polciy Loss: -7.079240322113037 | Steps: 7282
           | Alpha Value: tensor([0.0836]) | AlphaLoss: 0.35088399052619934 | Critic Loss: 2.592439889907837 | Critic 2 Loss: 3.0797739028930664
Episode: 16 | Reward: -38.17025925960655 | Polciy Loss: -8.375066757202148 | Steps: 8282
           | Alpha Value: tensor([0.0614]) | AlphaLoss: 0.2555815279483795 | Critic Loss: 4.223083019256592 | Critic 2 Loss: 4.096364974975586
Episode: 17 | Reward: -21.44949649228669 | Polciy Loss: -8.571939468383789 | Steps: 9282
           | Alpha Value: tensor([0.0451]) | AlphaLoss: 0.18620292842388153 | Critic Loss: 7.588921546936035 | Critic 2 Loss: 6.333924770355225
Episode: 18 | Reward: -49.33621525736231 | Polciy Loss: -7.181923866271973 | Steps: 9745
           | Alpha Value: tensor([0.0391]) | AlphaLoss: 0.16155092418193817 | Critic Loss: 29.392934799194336 | Critic 2 Loss: 29.366897583007812
Episode: 19 | Reward: -11.637710630285735 | Polciy Loss: -13.127476692199707 | Steps: 10745
           | Alpha Value: tensor([0.0287]) | AlphaLoss: 0.11814136803150177 | Critic Loss: 23.255800247192383 | Critic 2 Loss: 21.932920455932617
Episode: 20 | Reward: -184.09309040553893 | Polciy Loss: -13.604066848754883 | Steps: 11348
           | Alpha Value: tensor([0.0238]) | AlphaLoss: 0.09825044870376587 | Critic Loss: 6.0200653076171875 | Critic 2 Loss: 5.361664772033691
```